# Critique please - Arduino switching/dimming 24 V LED strip using 20 kHz PWM

Tags: arduino, led, pwm, mosfet-driver

I've created a circuit which allows me to dim a 24 V LED strip using 20 kHz PWM (because I'm interfacing with audio) from an Arduino.

I fully built the circuit and it runs cool and dims effectively, but I'm a novice and would like to know if there's something I've missed that could improve my circuit. I've included both the power side schematic and a picture of it built up on the breadboard. The latter also has a button to trigger some sample dimming sequences on the Arduino.

I haven't tested this to the full 5 A I'd like it to run, but I don't intend to test that on a breadboard.

[image]

[image: breadboard]

Comment: What's L7815 in your schematic?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! It's a 15V regulator. I'll upload a corrected schematic momentarily. I couldn't find this item in LTspice and tried to draw it in.

Comment: R1 is on the wrong side of 7815 in the schematic

Comment: @bobflux It's on that side of the 7815 in my breadboard circuit. Is there some reason it shouldn't be in that position? I figured limiting the current one way or the other would be fine... but now I realize I must be dropping some voltage before the regulator. It must be enough to trigger the MOSFET gate anyway. Is that right?

Comment: If the resistor is on the input, the 7815 output will be shorted to ground when the transistor turns on. Resistor limits the current so nothing will be damaged, but it will add a delay when it starts up again when the transistor turns off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overall design idea is on the right track, with the BJT acting as a gate driver for the MOSFET to bring its \$V_{GS}\$ up high enough for 5A of \$I_{ds}\$, and you seem to be grasping the basics, but there are some oversights that mean this isn't going to work.

(Un?)luckily for you, I've been working on a video series explaining exactly this topic, so I'm going to try to go through a whole design analysis here and explain all the gory details. This is a long answer, so maybe grab a beverage before you dive in :)

The first quick and easy fix is that R1 is in the wrong place. You want it after the regulator, not before.

You should also place a pair of 100nF ceramic decoupling capacitors physically close to the regulator - one between its output pin and ground pin, and the other between its input pin and a ground pin. Normally you'd want a fair bit more bulk decoupling than that, but your load current is small so you don't really need more.

The meat of the issue is that your MOSFET choice and R1 value look problematic.

The main concern is the on-resistance (\$R_{DS(on)}\$) rating for the IRF510, which is 0.54Ω at a gate-source voltage (\$V_{GS}\$) of 10V. No rating is given for a \$V_{GS}\$ of 15V, so we'll just use 10V here.

The dissipated power in the MOSFET will be \$P=I^2R\$, which is \$5^2 \times 0.54 = 13.5W\$. Given the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance (\$R_{thJA}\$) of 62°C/W, that's a temperature rise of \$13.5 \times 62 = 837°C\$. Your MOSFET is going to catch fire.

As a rough rule of thumb, you generally want to look for MOSFETs with an \$I_{DS(max)}\$ rating of at least twice your load current. You can then use its \$R_{DS(on)}\$ rating at the gate voltage you'll be using to figure out what the power dissipation will be, and then calculate the temperature rise using the thermal resistance rating of the package.

The 1kΩ value for R1 also seems like a problem due to the dynamic parameters of the MOSFET and your PWM frequency.

When Q2 switches off, current will start flowing from the regulator into the parasitic gate capacitance of M2. This current has to flow through R1 and R17. The total resistance ends up being 1220Ω plus the parasitic gate resistance (\$R_g\$) of the IRF510, which is a maximum of 11.6Ω. That means you've got 1231.6Ω of resistance in the gate charge path.

[This appnote on MOSFET gate charge](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf) is useful for determining the time it will take to switch a MOSFET on with a given gate resistance. It splits the turn-on transient into three timing regions:

[image: Figure 2 from the appnote]

\$t_1\$ is the time it takes for the MOSFET to reach the threshold voltage, where it begins to conduct (i.e. \$I_{DS}\$ rises above zero). \$t_2\$ is the time it takes for the MOSFET to reach the Miller plateau, which is also where \$I_{DS}\$ reaches its peak. \$t_3\$ is the time it takes for the MOSFET to exit the Miller plateau once it has entered it.

Since your load current is 5A and the \$I_{DS(max)}\$ of the MOSFET is 5.6A, we can assume that \$t_2\$ is roughly equal to the amount of time it'll take for your load to be fully switched on.

We can use equation 12 from the appnote to calculate \$t_2\$:

$$t_2 = R_G \times C_{iss}\times ln \left( \frac 1 {1 - \frac {V_{gp}} {V_{GS}} } \right)$$

where \$t\$ is time, \$R_G\$ is the total resistance between the gate and the voltage source, \$C_{iss}\$ is the input capacitance of the capacitor, \$V_{gp}\$ is the gate plateau voltage, \$V_{GS}\$ is the gate voltage being driven, and \$ln\$ is the natural log function.

We can get the values for \$C_{iss}\$ and \$V_{gp}\$ from [the IRF510 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91015/irf510.pdf). \$C_{iss}\$ is listed on the dynamic parameters table, with a typical value of 180pF. The plateau voltage can be read from Fig 6 (Typical Gate charge vs. Gate-to-Source Voltage).

[image: Qg vs Vgs from figure 6 of the IRF510 datasheet]

The gate plateau voltage is the \$V_{GS}\$ where the gate voltage "stalls" while the gate charge continues to increase, in this case around 7V. If you look at the \$V_{GS}\$ vs. \$I_D\$ graph (figure 3) from the datasheet, you can see that this aligns with the max rated current of 5.6A:

[image: Vgs vs. Id curve with the 7V gate voltage marked]

Based on these numbers, we can figure out the switch-on time:

$$t_2 = 1231.6\Omega \times 180pF \times ln \left( \frac 1 {1 - \frac {7V} {15V} } \right) = 139.4ns$$

You want to drive the gate with 20kHz PWM, which has a cycle period of 50 microseconds. This makes 139.4ns sound fast enough, but you actually need to consider the behaviour at the extremes of the duty cycle range. If you're using 8-bit PWM, the shortest pulse time is 1/255 of the cycle period, i.e. 196ns. This means that on the lowest duty cycle you're actually spending more than 70% of your time just switching the MOSFET on. This has implications for both power dissipation in your MOSFET (even if it wasn't already guaranteed to catch fire) due to the time the MOSFET spends in a resistive state, and for the minimum dimming level you can achieve.

The turn-off situation is the same in reverse but, since R1 is not involved in the turned-off state, the gate discharge path resistance is around 230Ω, which is a little less than one fifth the resistance of the gate charge path. Since \$t_2\$ is proportional to \$R_G\$, we can estimate that it takes around 30ns to turn the MOSFET back off (based on a rough estimate of \$t_3\$). So at high duty cycles (e.g. 254/255) you'll still be ok.

All of this is to say that you're going to have trouble with this design and component choice.

Now, how do you fix this?

First, you're going to need a better MOSFET. Pick one with an \$I_{DS(max)}\$ of at least 10A. I'd personally look for something around 15-20A, since the price difference is going to be essentially zero. Make sure its \$V_{GS(max)}\$ exceeds 15V (unless you choose to use a logic-level MOSFET; more on that later). Then figure out what the \$R_{DS(on)}\$ will be at 15V, and use \$P=I^2R\$ to calculate the power dissipation in the MOSFET in its on-state. Multiply that by the \$R_{thJA}\$ of the package to figure out the worst case temperature rise above ambient. Ideally you want to keep this small, because all the other parameters of the MOSFET will start to derate as the temperature climbs. Remember that you need to add your worst-case ambient temperature to the temperature rise to get the actual operating temperature.

Next, you need to reconsider your driver circuit. It's ok for slow switching, but for 20kHz 8-bit PWM it's not great.

The first thing to consider is R17. MOSFET gate resistors aren't used for the same reason as base resistors on BJTs. With a BJT you need a gate resistor to limit the \$I_{BE}\$ current. With a MOSFET, gate resistors can often be omitted entirely.

A common case where you might want to include a gate resistor is if you're driving the gate directly from a GPIO pin, since you want to limit the current flowing in/out of that pin to within the max source/sink current rating of the GPIO. In such a case you can use Ohm's law to figure out the resistance you need - you've got a GPIO pin at a given VCC voltage, connected to a discharged gate at 0V, and the MCU's datasheet will tell you the maximum current you can draw/sink. So you can use \$R=\frac V I\$ to calculate the necessary gate resistance.

Gate resistors are also sometimes used to prevent ringing and EMI on gate drivers when switching MOSFETs very quickly (hundreds of kHz or MHz).

You'll also sometimes see a configuration where two resistors are placed in parallel, with one resistor having a diode in series with it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKM0JH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is used for *asymmetric* gate drive current. R2 is lower than R1. When the gate is being charged, the current must pass through R1. When the gate is being discharged, the current can pass through R1 *and* D1/R2, so the gate can discharge more quickly. This avoids a problem called parasitic self-turn-on, which is to do with the plateau we saw above in the gate charge graph. Essentially, while the MOSFET is in the process of turning off, the parasitic capacitance at the MOSFET gate can create a capacitive voltage divider effect between the drain, gate, and source, and cause the internal voltage at the gate to jump back up, above \$V_{gs(th)}\$, which causes the MOSFET to unexpectedly turn itself back on! This can be catastrophic in push-pull configurations because it leads to shoot-through, where the supply rail is essentially shorted to ground through the MOSFETs. This isn't so much of a worry for your use-case.

If you remove R17, that takes care of part of the problem, but you've still got a bunch of resistance from R1. The problem now is that if you reduce R1 to get lower gate charge resistance, you're shunting much more current through Q2 while it is switched on, which is inefficient and is going to heat up both R1 and Q2. Finding a balance between a low enough R1 to get good switching performance but high enough R1 to avoid wasting power and heating up your components is tricky.

Luckily there are other options.

The easiest is to just buy a logic-level MOSFET that'll handle 5A of \$I_{DS}\$ with a \$V_{GS}\$ of 5V or less, and drive the gate from the GPIO with a 120Ω resistor in series with the gate (based on 40mA max GPIO current and 5V drive).

If you can't find a logic-level MOSFET that'll fit your requirements (or it's too expensive) you can use a MOSFET driver IC. For your case you want a low-side MOSFET driver. They're cheap and super simple - typically you'll have a power pin, ground pin, gate drive pin, and logic level input pin. You give it some power, hook the input pin to a GPIO, the gate drive pin to the gate (possibly through a small series resistor - see the driver datasheet for details), and that's it. It does all the driving magic for you!

Alternatively, if you're set on building your own MOSFET driver from discrete parts, you can construct a push-pull driver. There are lots of designs for this, but I'm a fan of an adaptation of Prof. Sam Ben-Yaakov's split resistor push-pull driver from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wQD0FSRkkQ).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSQMlc.png)</sup>

The linked video explains it in detail, but here's a quick overview:

- M1 and M2 are small MOSFETs (P-channel on top, N-channel on bottom) which form a push-pull driver. These are chosen with a \$V_{GS(max)}\$ high enough to withstand the gate drive voltage.
- R1 and R2 are asymmetric drive resistors. R1 is typically larger than R2. This allows M3's gate to discharge more quickly than it charges, and avoid any self turn on effects. Sensible values for most cases are somewhere around 10Ω for R1 and 2Ω for R2. Typically R1 and R2 are both rated for 1W or so (rather than 1/16W or 1/8W of your typical SMD resistor) so that they can handle the short high-current pulses during switching transients.
- Q1 acts as a voltage level translator from the output voltage of the MCU to the MOSFET gate drive voltage.
- When the input is high, Q1 switches on, and pulls the gates of M1 and M2 to 0V.

  - Since M1 is a P-channel FET, a low gate-source voltage means it switches on, so a current flows through it and charges M3's gate through R1.
  - Since M2 is an N-channel FET, a low gate-source voltage means it switches off, so it does not conduct and no current can flow through R2 and M2 to ground.
- When the input is low, Q1 switches off, and R3 pulls the gates of M1 and M2 high. Since M1 and M2 are small, and they aren't switching large currents, they have low effective gate capacitance and can be quickly switched without a lot of current, so it's ok if R3 is 1kΩ or more.

  - Since M1 is a P-channel FET, a high gate-source voltage means it switches off, and no current can flow through it.
  - Since M2 is an N-channel FET, a high gate-source voltage means it switches on, and M3's gate discharges through R2.
- If M1 and M2 don't turn on/off at the exact same rate, both of them could be conducting at once. This is the main problem with push-pull drivers, because you get shoot-through where there's a path from power to ground through the MOSFETs. However, in this configuration, the path has to go through M1, through R1, through R2, through M2, and then to ground. This increases the total resistance of the shoot-through path. If you test this out, it turns out that the magnitude of the transient shoot-through energy is lower than the magnitude of the gate drive energy. This is much better than other designs.

If you want the gate drive voltage to be different to the load drive voltage, you can take the same approach as in your original circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwl4F1.png)</sup>

If you're scratching your head a bit, don't worry. High speed MOSFET drivers are actually hard work to build. Understanding them is a lot of fun, but if you just want to get on with a design then you can skip the design lesson and just opt for a logic-level MOSFET or a gate driver IC.

And that's just about it. I hope you learned a bunch :)

As a very last quick aside, something to watch out for is the base current when you're driving BJTs from a GPIO. A 220Ω base resistor (R4) is probably a little on the low side. With your MCU outputting 5V, you'll have about 20mA of current flowing from the Arduino's GPIO into the base of Q2. That's within the limits of the Atmega328P, but it's still a bit excessive, and with other MCUs you might not be allowed to source as much as 20mA from a GPIO pin. The current amplification behaviour of a BJT is roughly \$I_C = I_B \times \beta\$ (where \$\beta\$ is sometimes listed as \$h_{FE}\$ in datasheets). Given that \$\beta\$ is in the range of 100-300 for the 2N3904 in the design you're using, 20mA of gate current gets you anywhere between 2A and 6A of \$I_{CE}\$ current, which is more than enough. You can tone down the base current a bit. Alternatively, you can just swap the BJT out for a small N-channel MOSFET (e.g. 2N7002) in exactly the same configuration and not worry about base current at all.

Comment: Your answer is great for the more advanced folks, but this guy is clearly a beginner who needs basic explanations from which he can build upon when he's grasped the basics. Yours is a scholarly approach which dumps all the necessary details that usually overwhelm the student and often leave him confused or even scared off and disinterested in pursuing a more detailed study of electronics. I know because I'm one of those. I LOVE electronics and science in general, but when a bunch a math is dumped at me, I mostly skip it. It is only at a more ripe age when I seek the details as needed.

Comment: Given OP's design, it looks like they have a good grasp of the basics of using MOSFETs. I discussed all the deep details involved because it's a great design case to explore some of the lesser talked-about behaviours of MOSFETs that do actually matter in practical designs of this type, and far too many tutorials skip over critical details like parasitic capacitance and switching time. I'd rather cover things in great detail, explaining all the terms as I go, and then have a conversation with OP about anything that was unclear, than leave people with a half-understanding that bites them later.

Comment: For me, the most frustrating thing in the world was learning about MOSFETs and then trying to build a circuit using the exact advice that was given, only to find out that it didn't work, leaving me wondering if I was just bad at electronics and out of my depth. That feeling is extremely demoralising. More often than not, it turned out that the explanation I was working from had skipped or handwaved over some critical detail in an effort to make the explanation sound simpler. So, given my experience, I'd rather err on the side of completeness.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I will go over your answer a couple more times because it is so useful. I am familiar with almost everything you wrote above, but it is a good refresher and you gave a few useful approaches/details. I am currently trying to build a two-way DC-DC converter going from about 170-180V solar power to 12V lead-acid batteries, and then back to about 150-160V DC for LED reflectors. So much to choose from: a single half-bridge push-pull transformer, a single transformer bi-directional DAB, or a multi-phase multi-transformer forward converter. Scratching my head for months now.

Comment: Both answers are amazing! My background: I've been digging into a couple of EE topics every day on YouTube for a few months and I've gone through an Arduino kit. I've also fried an Uno, a MOSFET and a couple of TC4420 chips on this project. I have a BSME but from 20 yrs ago and what I've done since then is a long story. Very happy for the replies and when I can process them I will!

Comment: @eemoob No worries. If you do find any part of it confusing, or need any clarifications, let me know and I'm happy to go over it with you :)

Answer (score 2):

The circuit looks a OK for starters except for the R1 resistor being placed before instead of after the LM7815, plus you should use maybe a 9V or 10 regulator instead (LM7809 or LM7810).
Also, just a few components/capacitors are needed for stability.
Here is a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuBaal.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. You need to place at least 0.33uF capacitor at the input of the voltage regulator LM7810 and at least 0.1uF at its output. I have used 1uF caps which should be fine. They are needed for stability and to prevent oscillations.
2. You should use a 9V or 10V regulator as that is high enough to ensure full turn on of the MOSFET, but also a faster turn off; the higher you charge the MOSFET gate, the longer it takes to turn it off.
3. The LM78xx voltage regulators have a minimum load current requirement of about 5mA to keep regulating the voltage, so I have added the 220 ohm resistor (R4) for that purpose.
4. The 1000 ohm resistor R1 before the regulator would be dropping voltage too low before it reaches the regulator, and that could cause problems with the regulator and MOSFET switching. I have placed it AFTER the regulator. 
   Its purpose is to provide full turn on voltage for MOSFET gate when Q1 is off, and to limit the current and ensure near zero volts when Q1 is on to turn off the MOSFET.
5. I have decreased the gate resistor R2 to 10 ohms. Its purpose is to dampen oscillations/ringing on the gate during switching, and such a low value is sufficient for that. It is not needed to limit the current to MOSFET gate like with the bipolar junction transistors (BJT like the 2N3904), because the gate-source "junction" acts like a small capacitor; once it's charged up, there is practically no current through it.
   Making the gate resistor much larger increases the time it takes to turn the MOSFET on or off, meaning the MOSFET spends more time acting like a resistor and less as a switch, making it waste more power and dissipate more heat, possibly burning it in extreme cases.
6. I have increased the Q1 base resistor R5 value to reduce the load on the Arduino, but that increases the MOSFET turn off time somewhat. You could lower it to 330 ohms but no less because of the 30mA output current limit for Arduino.
7. I suggest you use a MOSFET which has a much lower on resistance than the IRF510, which means less heat dissipated in it. IRF3205 is something you could use instead. 
   IRF510 has 0.540 ohms, while IRF3205 has 0.008 ohms RdsON resistance. At 5A, the 510 would drop 2.7V and waste 13.5W in heat, needing a large heatsink or burning the MOSFET without it! The 3205 would drop only 0.04V and waste 0.2W on heat, which would only make it warm without heatsink.
8. I suggest you use a C3 capacitor between MOSFET source pin (ground) and positive 24V output to LED strips to prevent voltage drops and oscillations in circuit during switching.
9. Observe the negative supply (ground) wire routing, my drawing choice here was deliberate: I have placed it at the MOSFET's source pin because it sends most current to the ground. This ensures it gets the "lowest zero volts", so to speak, as placing it elsewhere would produce higher voltage drops throughout the circuit and raise the ground pins above zero volts, causing problems/instability.
10. Finally, instead of the voltage regulator, you could use a simple 10V zener or two 5.1V zeners in series going from the top of R1 to the ground, with a dropping resistor of about 3300 ohms, as the MOSFET gate would need about 3mA driving current (voltage regulator needs 5mA load to ensure regulation, plus about 5mA its own, quiescent current, totalling 10mA PLUS MOSFET gate current = 13mA), plus a capacitor of about 1-10uF across the zener(s). 
    This would reduce your control circuit current consumption from 12-14mA to about 4mA, although you may not care about it with a 5A load.

Comment: Careful: C3 needs to have a ripple current rating of at least 5A at the switching frequency, otherwise self-heating (from ESR/DF) will cause it to fail. I'd honestly just omit it entirely unless there's a demonstrable need for additional bulk decoupling, and even then I'd consider using ceramics (MLCCs) on the LED strip itself for localised decoupling instead.

Comment: The IRF3205 also has a huge input capacitance - 20 times that of the IRF510. So at lower duty cycles, with R1 being 1kΩ, the LEDs will never actually reach their turn-on current and you'll just be heating up the MOSFET for no reason.

Comment: Wouldn't caps on strips increase the surge currents? Maybe an RC snubber across the voltage rails on strips? The 470uF here was just some bare minimum for the control circuit itself, not really trying to meet the surge demand of the strips. Their resistance plus any additional wire resistance is likely more than the ESR of this capacitor.

Comment: Ah, good point about the MLCCs on the strips, I wasn't thinking straight there - you're right, it needs to be from +V to GND _outside_ of the MOSFET, not across the strip itself. Not due to surge currents, but just because it'll stop the PWM from working properly. Still, though, I'd just omit C3 - the impedance of the power delivery path should be low enough, so there's no need for decoupling unless there's an expectation of massively long power leads with tons of parasitic inductance.

Comment: The gate driver circuit is still fully broken, though. A MOSFET with that much input capacitance needs a proper driver.

Comment: @Polynomial You're right, it could definitely use a better driver, at least an NPN-PNP pair after R1.